# Upgrading angular material broke the md-input line breaks

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I had this log in form when I was running an old material version.
I decided to upgrade to make use of the new features.

After the update, the form broke so instead of showing the inputs on different lines, they are showing in the same line as below:

BEFORE THE UPDATE

[image]

AFTER THE UPDATE

[image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-container">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:;">

                <md-input-container md-no-float>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email" required>
                </md-input-container>     

                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Type your password" ng-model="password" required>
                </md-input-container>
    </form>

</div>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: `This is the code:` But there's no code?

Comment: sorry @Roope, there it is

Answer (score 1):

Just use `class="md-block"` on the `md-input-container`s - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PzAago)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="form-container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:;">

      <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email" required>
      </md-input-container>     

      <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Type your password" ng-model="password" required>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: The above method is the correct Angular Material way but if you want to reduce the gap between the two inputs just use a bit of CSS - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/OXZoVx)

Markup

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" id="password">
```

CSS

```
#password {
  margin-top: -10px
}
```

Comment: Thanks @camden_kid. The thing is that if I add that it shows a very big gep in between the inputs (same behavior as if i surround both inputs on a div)

Comment: @AlejandroLozdziejski - Sorry, I've been changing the answer a bit. Were you responding to `layout="column` or `md-block`? The latter is the better solution.